# My Chromebook, running Linux, won't boot

Tags: ubuntu, chrome-book, chrome-os, hp

I have a HP Chromebook G14 ([see specs](https://www.google.com/chromebook/device/hp-chromebook-14-g4/)) from which I removed Chrome OS and installed Ubuntu 22.04.  To do this I followed the steps in the
[How To: Install Ubuntu on Chromebook and REMOVE Chrome OS](https://dbtechreviews.com/2018/09/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-chromebook-and-remove-chromeos/) tutorial,
which worked well, initially.

After using it happily for a couple of weeks, the laptop ran out of batteries before I could charge it up,
and now I can't get past the Chrome OS boot screens.

I've tried all the normal things,
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, etc.

When I turn it on, I get the normal... 
[image: Initial boot screen]

> OS verification is Off 
> Press SPACE to re-enable.

Then... 
[image: second boot screen]

> Chrome OS is missing or damaged. 
> Please insert a recovery USB stick or SD card.

If I hit Tab, I get some extra info... 
[image: "chrome" screen with diagnostic/error text overlaid]

> ```
> HWID: KIP E3B-H8C-O7Q-B6A-A4H
> recovery_reason: 0x5b  No bootable kernel found on disk
> VbSD.flags: 0x00002c50
> VbNv.raw: 70 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20
> dev_boot_usb: 0
> dev_boot_legacy: 0
> dev_boot_signed_only: 0
> TPM: fwver=0x00190003 kernver=0x00030001
> gbb.flags: 0x00000000
> gbb.rootkey: c788cee8c798669fe4822b7544dd3e399ce22604
> gbb.recovery_key: 6eaa4b094cd75eacc0f2fa4516d33ed86ea6f3d2
> read-only firmware id: Google_Kip.5216.227.25
> active firmware id: Google_Kip.5216.227.25
> ```

<sup>[Manually transcribed]</sup>

So I can't get past these screens at all.

I know, it's maybe unwise to do this in the first place,
but if anyone could help, that'd be amazing.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, thats a bad, confused guide. If I followed it correctly, it gets you to install Linux OS on your second usb drive, which would explain why you cant boot without the drive plugged in. Plug in the usb stick you used and boot from there.

Comment: Yea, it's not totally clear, but in my case I installed Linux on the MMC storage on the laptop's motherboard.

Comment: All informaton I found online ussually points to a corrupt drive. Try livebooting ubuntu again and poke around in your partitions; if it works, then you can just reinstall. Otherwise, you might have to use your warranty (if you have it).

Comment: Thanks for time and thoughts.  I can't currently boot to anything other then a ChromeOS restore USB.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Chrome using the recovery details provided in the screenshot (right where it says `Model`) by following the link.
2. Once recovered, boot into Chrome by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, and log in as user `root`. Try '1234' as password.
3. Open a terminal, and enter `sudo crossystem dev_boot_usb=1`.

Everything is still in the NVRAM, but it's lost due to losing the battery charge in its entirety.

The best thing would be to replace the SSD or to use an external USB 3 and store the Chrome SSD somewhere safe.

Comment: So, are you saying that the user should reinstall ChromeOS, which they previously, deliberately removed?  Please be clearer.

Comment: … and what does “login as `root` test `1234`” mean? … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete. … … … @telometto:   Perhaps you can answer this question, as you added the current formatting.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I don't know what the hell I must've been drinking yesterday, because that came out as absolute gore. I'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

see mrchromebook for the scripts to install the new bios to boot to native Linux.

https://mrchromebox.tech/